# Java Regex .split String of CFGs

Tags: java, regex, split

Been having problems parsing a line String from a CFG file,

the input string is:

```
String str = "The <animal> loves to <activity>.";
```

I've tried to use split with regex to split by the Non-terminals (<*>), however it's not producing the desired results:

What I've tried:

```
str.split("(?=<)");

Output:

"The ", "<animal> loves to", "<activity>."
```

Desired output:

```
"The ", "<animal>", " loves to ", "<activity>", "."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split using lookarounds:

```
String str = "The <animal> loves to <activity>.";
String[] parts = str.split("(?=<)|(?<=>)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[The , <animal>,  loves to , <activity>, .]
```

The splitting logic used above says to split at any point in the string when `>` immediately precedes or when `<` immediately follows.

Comment: Is this the fastest way of doing this? or is there a faster way?, it seems that my previous implementation where I parse using charAt and substring seems to be faster.

Comment: Yes, a solution using the base string functions would likely outperform regex, but would be more code.

Comment: Regex is rarely the fastest solution.